# Output list of pdf files as one pdf using pdftk bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pdftk, filelist

I have a bash script containing a list of PDF files. 
The printer output is tailored by commenting/ uncommenting file requirement (see example script below).
I wish to add to this so I can choose to print all selected files to a single pdf using  pdftk (or the paper printer). I am familiar with pdftk though not bash.

Can anyone indicate the bash code to output as one PDF ?

Thank you

```
!/bin/bash

# Print document pack

# Instructions
#   ls > print.txt                  Generate the file list into a file 
#   -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -#1        Prints two sided long edge, one copy
#   -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -#2        Prints two sided long edge, two copies
#   -o page-ranges=1 -#1                Print first page only, one copy
#   -o page-ranges=1-2,5-7 -#1          Print pages 1-2 & 5-7 only, one copy

#   -lt x                       sets number of packs to be printed
#   while [  $COUNTER -lt  ***** 1 ****** ]; do     NUMBER INSIDE STARS INDICATES NUMBER PACKS TO PRINT

COUNTER=0

while [  $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do

    lpr "doc01.pdf"

    lpr "doc02.pdf"

    lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -#1 "doc03.pdf"

#   lpr "doc04.pdf"

#   lpr "doc05.pdf"

    lpr -o sides=one-sided-long-edge -o page-ranges=1 -#1 "doc06.pdf"

#   lpr "doc07.pdf"

    lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -#2 "doc08.pdf"

    lpr "doc09.pdf"

    lpr "doc10.pdf"

let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```

Comment: Have you had a look at pdftk's man page?

Comment: Hi @Biffen. Yes I have. I am familiar with pdftk though not bash.

Comment: Where did the bash script come from? Do the file names just appear like that, or are they assigned to some variable?

Comment: @Biffen I haven't got a bash script yet. what I have got I have pasted into modified question above ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()

add() {
  files+=("'""$1""'")
}

add "file1.pdf"

#add "file2.pdf"

add "file3.pdf"

add "file with     spaces.pdf"

echo "${files[*]}"
```

Naturally, substitute the proper `pdftk` command for `echo`.

---

**Edit 2**

This new "version" will work better with filenames containing spaces.

---

**Edit 3**

To hand the files over to the command, it seems something like the following will do the trick:

```
bash -c "stat $(echo "${files[*]}")"
```

Comment: tried `code`pdftk $files output newfile.pdf`code` as well as `code`echo pdftk $files output newfile.pdf`code` and some variants. I think the problem is something to do with escaping the concatenated string through bash to pdftk

Comment: works perfectly for pdf file names with no spaces. There are spaces in all the file names eg "doc 1.pdf" so need to be able to pass this through bash. THANK YOU !

Comment: yes ... tried edits and seems very tricky. Glad UR around !! What should I do with the .... "bash -c ... " command. Not sure I follow. THANK YOU !

Comment: @user1062153 Replace `echo "${files[*]}"` with `bash -c "pdftk $(echo "${files[*]}") -o output.pdf"` (or whatever the `pdftk` command would be). The quoting sure got tricky, but I've tested this and it seems to work right.

Comment: superb ! Thank you @Biffen. Don't know what I would have done without your help !